# How to add overwrite(dialog option) in Swing java?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file, joptionpane

I created an overwrite file option by using `.exists` command.

But its saving the same files again in the selected destined path!

```
File f = new File(destPathStr);
File[] destFilesList = f.listFiles();
if (f.exists()) {
    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, //
            "Do you want to replace the existing file?", //
            "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, //
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (response != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        return duplicate;
    } 
}
```

I am having files stored in variable called "f".

But in my code it is not working and I stuck where to make it.

This above part of my snippet code is from:

```
public boolean checkFileDuplicate(String destPathStr) //line 273
```

here is my full code below:

```
public class swingfinal implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblSourceFolderfiles;
    private JButton btnChoosedirectoryfrom;
    private JLabel lblListFilesBelow;
    private JButton btnDisplay;
    private JTextField destPath;
    private JTextField searchBox;
    private JCheckBox chckbxSelectAll;
    private JLabel lblNoOfFiles;
    private JTextField noOfFileTxt;
    private JButton btnGenerate;
    private JLabel lblDestinationFolderTo;
    private JButton btnBrowse;
    private JPanel middlePanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;

    //Objects
    private List<Box> boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
    private List<JCheckBox> checkBoxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
    private Map<String, String> fileNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    //Variables
    private int selectedCounter;

    public swingfinal() { 
        frame = new javax.swing.JFrame( "Search Box" );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
        frame.setSize( 1200, 720 );
        frame.setVisible(true);

        lblSourceFolderfiles = new JLabel("Source Folder/ Files");
        lblSourceFolderfiles.setBounds(6, 17, 138, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSourceFolderfiles);

        btnChoosedirectoryfrom = new JButton("ChooseDirectory From");
        btnChoosedirectoryfrom.addActionListener(this);
        btnChoosedirectoryfrom.setBounds(141, 9, 170, 30);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnChoosedirectoryfrom);

        lblListFilesBelow = new JLabel("List files Below to choose ");
        lblListFilesBelow.setBounds(344, 17, 180, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblListFilesBelow);

        btnDisplay = new JButton("Select To Display");
        btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
        btnDisplay.setBounds(534, 9, 180, 30);
        btnDisplay.addActionListener( this );
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnDisplay);

        searchBox = new JTextField();
        searchBox.setBounds( 25, 50, 750, 40 );
        searchBox.setFont( new Font( "Latha", Font.BOLD, 20 ) );
        searchBox.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.CENTER );
        frame.getContentPane().add( searchBox );

        middlePanel = new JPanel ();
        middlePanel.setBorder ( new TitledBorder ( new EtchedBorder (), "Display Area" ) );
        middlePanel.setBounds(25, 110, 1100, 400);

        chckbxSelectAll = new JCheckBox("Select All");
        chckbxSelectAll.setBounds(25, 557, 97, 23);
        chckbxSelectAll.addActionListener(this);    
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxSelectAll);

        lblNoOfFiles = new JLabel("NO of Files Selected");
        lblNoOfFiles.setBounds(41, 607, 139, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNoOfFiles);

        noOfFileTxt = new JTextField();
        noOfFileTxt.setBounds(163, 597, 125, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(noOfFileTxt);
        noOfFileTxt.setColumns(10);

        btnGenerate = new JButton("Generate");
        btnGenerate.setBounds(371, 584, 89, 60);
        btnGenerate.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGenerate);

        lblDestinationFolderTo = new JLabel("Select Destination Path To Generate Files");
        lblDestinationFolderTo.setBounds(553, 571, 259, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblDestinationFolderTo);

        btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
        btnBrowse.setBounds(822, 567, 89, 23);
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

        destPath = new JTextField();
        destPath.setBounds( 553, 600, 400, 30 );
        destPath.setFont( new Font( "Latha", Font.BOLD, 20 ) );
        frame.getContentPane().add( destPath );
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("ChooseDirectory From")) {
            chooseDirectoryFrom();
        } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Select To Display")) {
            selectToDisplay();
        } else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Select All")) {
            selectAllMethod();
        } else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Browse")) {
            outputDirSelection();
        } else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Generate")) {
            generate();
        }
    }

    public void chooseDirectoryFrom() {
        String tempStr = null;
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            Font font = new Font("Latha", Font.ITALIC, 10);
            fileChooser.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.PLAIN, 13));
            fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            fileChooser.setFont(font);

            int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                tempStr = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();
            }
            if (tempStr != null && !tempStr.trim().equals("")) {
                searchBox.setText(tempStr);
                // Enable the search button
                btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void selectToDisplay() {
        File sourceFolder = null;
        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        if (boxList.size() != 0) {
            middlePanel.remove(scrollPane);
            middlePanel.repaint();
            frame.repaint();
            boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
            checkBoxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
            fileNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            selectedCounter = 0;
            noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
        }
        sourceFolder = new File(searchBox.getText());
        File[] sourceFilesList = sourceFolder.listFiles();
        JCheckBox cb1 = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceFilesList.length; i++) {
            if (sourceFilesList[i].isFile() & sourceFilesList[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                fileNamesMap.put(sourceFilesList[i].getAbsolutePath(), sourceFilesList[i].getName());
                cb1 = new JCheckBox(sourceFilesList[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
                cb1.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.BOLD, 20));
                box.add(cb1);
                checkBoxList.add(cb1);
                cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).isSelected()) {
                            selectedCounter += 1;
                        } else {
                            selectedCounter -= 1;
                            if (selectedCounter < 0) {
                                selectedCounter = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        boxList.add(box);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(box);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1050, 350));
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        middlePanel.add ( scrollPane );
        frame.getContentPane().add(middlePanel);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.revalidate();
    }

    public void selectAllMethod() {
        Iterator<JCheckBox> i = checkBoxList.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            JCheckBox tmp = i.next();
            if (chckbxSelectAll.isSelected()) {
                tmp.doClick();
            } else {
                tmp.setSelected(false);
                selectedCounter -= 1;
                if (selectedCounter < 0) {
                    selectedCounter = 0;
                }
                noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
            }
        }
    }

    public void generate() {
        Iterator<JCheckBox> i = checkBoxList.iterator();
        boolean once=false;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            JCheckBox chkBox = i.next();
                if(chkBox.isSelected()) {
                    String fileName =  chkBox.getText();
                    String destPathStr = destPath.getText();
                    System.out.println("filepathname = " + fileName);
                if(destPathStr != null) {
                    System.out.println("destPath: " + destPath.getText());
                    System.out.println("fileName: " + fileNamesMap.get(fileName));

                    boolean success = ex1final.exlCreator(fileName, destPath.getText(), fileNamesMap.get(fileName));
                    if(success&&!once)  {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Completed. Pls refer to the path " +  destPathStr + " for output files"); once=true;  
                    }  else if (once!=true) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Error Occured!!!");once=true;
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OOPS.You have to set the destination path!!!");
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public void outputDirSelection() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            destPath.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    public boolean checkFileDuplicate(String destPathStr) {
        boolean duplicate = false;
        File f = new File(destPathStr);
        File[] destFilesList = f.listFiles();
        if (f.exists()) {
            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, //
                    "Do you want to replace the existing file?", //
                    "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, //
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (response != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                return duplicate;
            } 
        }
        for(File f1:destFilesList) {
            duplicate = fileNamesMap.containsKey(f1.getName());

            if(duplicate == true) {
                return duplicate;
            }
        }
        f = null;
        destFilesList = null;
        return duplicate;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new swingfinal();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is checkFileDuplicate supposed to do, it is not used in your code. Nitpick: Javaclass are named in CamelCase by Convention, so your class should be named SwingFinal

Comment: I just created it for file overwrite option just a try code!!

Comment: Ok, now tell me what the boolean you return should be interpreted as. Does it mean there is a duplicate?

Comment: `checkFileDuplicate` is not used in the code you pasted here, also this part `ex1final.exlCreator(fileName, destPath.getText(), fileNamesMap.get(fileName));` does not compile

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.